# Pandas groupby, melt and drop in one go

Tags: python, pandas

I want to add column to the dataframe with values(comments) based on the Timestamp, grouped per each day.
I made it as per example below, but... is there any other more "pandonic" way? maybe one-liner or at least close to it?

Example data frame (the actual has much more dates and more different values):

```
import pandas as pd

data = {"Values": ["absd","abse", "dara", "absd","abse", "dara"],
"Date": ["2022-05-25","2022-05-25","2022-05-25", "2022-05-26","2022-05-26","2022-05-26"],
"Timestamp": ["2022-05-25 08:00:00", "2022-05-25 11:30:00", "2022-05-25 20:25:00", 
              "2022-05-26 09:00:00", "2022-05-26 13:40:00", "2022-05-26 19:15:00"]}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df.Timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.Timestamp, format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S')
df.Date = pd.to_datetime(df.Date, format='%Y-%m-%d')
```

df out:

```
  Values       Date           Timestamp
0   absd 2022-05-25 2022-05-25 08:00:00
1   abse 2022-05-25 2022-05-25 11:30:00
2   dara 2022-05-25 2022-05-25 20:25:00
3   absd 2022-05-26 2022-05-26 09:00:00
4   abse 2022-05-26 2022-05-26 13:40:00
5   dara 2022-05-26 2022-05-26 19:15:00
```

the end result I want is:

```
Values       Date Period            Datetime
0    absd 2022-05-25  Start 2022-05-25 08:00:00
1    abse 2022-05-25  Start 2022-05-25 08:00:00
2    dara 2022-05-25  Start 2022-05-25 08:00:00
3    dara 2022-05-25    Mid 2022-05-25 11:30:00
4    abse 2022-05-25    Mid 2022-05-25 11:30:00
5    absd 2022-05-25    Mid 2022-05-25 11:30:00
6    dara 2022-05-25    End 2022-05-25 20:25:00
7    abse 2022-05-25    End 2022-05-25 20:25:00
8    absd 2022-05-25    End 2022-05-25 20:25:00
9    dara 2022-05-26  Start 2022-05-26 09:00:00
10   abse 2022-05-26  Start 2022-05-26 09:00:00
11   absd 2022-05-26  Start 2022-05-26 09:00:00
12   absd 2022-05-26    Mid 2022-05-26 13:40:00
13   abse 2022-05-26    Mid 2022-05-26 13:40:00
14   dara 2022-05-26    Mid 2022-05-26 13:40:00
15   absd 2022-05-26    End 2022-05-26 19:15:00
16   abse 2022-05-26    End 2022-05-26 19:15:00
17   dara 2022-05-26    End 2022-05-26 19:15:00
```

my working approach is below:

```
df["Start"] = df["Timestamp"].groupby(df["Date"]).transform("min")
df["End"] = df["Timestamp"].groupby(df["Date"]).transform("max")
df["Mid"] = df["Timestamp"].groupby(df["Date"]).transform("median")

df1 = df.melt(id_vars = ["Values","Date"],
    var_name="Period",value_name="Datetime").sort_values("Datetime")

df1 = df1[df1.Period != "Timestamp"].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another pandas only method:

```
out = (df.groupby('Date')
         .agg({'Timestamp':['min', 'median', 'max'], 'Values':list})
         .explode(('Values', 'list'))
         .droplevel(0, axis=1)
         .rename(columns={'list':'Values'})
         .reset_index()
         .melt(['Values', 'Date'], var_name='Period', value_name='Datetime')
         .sort_values('Datetime', ignore_index=True))
print(out)
```

Output:

```
   Values       Date  Period            Datetime
0    absd 2022-05-25     min 2022-05-25 08:00:00
1    abse 2022-05-25     min 2022-05-25 08:00:00
2    dara 2022-05-25     min 2022-05-25 08:00:00
3    abse 2022-05-25  median 2022-05-25 11:30:00
4    absd 2022-05-25  median 2022-05-25 11:30:00
5    dara 2022-05-25  median 2022-05-25 11:30:00
6    absd 2022-05-25     max 2022-05-25 20:25:00
7    abse 2022-05-25     max 2022-05-25 20:25:00
8    dara 2022-05-25     max 2022-05-25 20:25:00
9    abse 2022-05-26     min 2022-05-26 09:00:00
10   absd 2022-05-26     min 2022-05-26 09:00:00
11   dara 2022-05-26     min 2022-05-26 09:00:00
12   absd 2022-05-26  median 2022-05-26 13:40:00
13   abse 2022-05-26  median 2022-05-26 13:40:00
14   dara 2022-05-26  median 2022-05-26 13:40:00
15   abse 2022-05-26     max 2022-05-26 19:15:00
16   absd 2022-05-26     max 2022-05-26 19:15:00
17   dara 2022-05-26     max 2022-05-26 19:15:00
```

Answer (score 2):

From the end result dataframe, it looks like you need a combination of all the columns (well, a combination of the `Values` column and the ('Date', Timestamp') columns).

One option is with [complete](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/api/functions/#janitor.functions.complete.complete) from [pyjanitor](https://pyjanitor-devs.github.io/pyjanitor/):

```py
# pip install pyjanitor
import pandas as pd
import janitor

(df
.assign(Period = ['Start', 'Mid', 'End'] * 2)
.complete(('Date', 'Timestamp', 'Period'), 'Values')
)
   Values       Date           Timestamp Period
0    absd 2022-05-25 2022-05-25 08:00:00  Start
1    abse 2022-05-25 2022-05-25 08:00:00  Start
2    dara 2022-05-25 2022-05-25 08:00:00  Start
3    absd 2022-05-25 2022-05-25 11:30:00    Mid
4    abse 2022-05-25 2022-05-25 11:30:00    Mid
5    dara 2022-05-25 2022-05-25 11:30:00    Mid
6    absd 2022-05-25 2022-05-25 20:25:00    End
7    abse 2022-05-25 2022-05-25 20:25:00    End
8    dara 2022-05-25 2022-05-25 20:25:00    End
9    absd 2022-05-26 2022-05-26 09:00:00  Start
10   abse 2022-05-26 2022-05-26 09:00:00  Start
11   dara 2022-05-26 2022-05-26 09:00:00  Start
12   absd 2022-05-26 2022-05-26 13:40:00    Mid
13   abse 2022-05-26 2022-05-26 13:40:00    Mid
14   dara 2022-05-26 2022-05-26 13:40:00    Mid
15   absd 2022-05-26 2022-05-26 19:15:00    End
16   abse 2022-05-26 2022-05-26 19:15:00    End
17   dara 2022-05-26 2022-05-26 19:15:00    End
```

Comment: Thanks a lot :) have not yet used janitor, will be interesting to read about it.
as per `.complete`, documentation have not even got it close explain the solution you used. Especially confusing the first part, `.assign(Period = ['Start', 'Mid', 'End'] * 2)` - why `*2`?

Comment: you have a total of six elements in the `Values` column, in pairs of three, that's why I created start, mid, end twice. if your data is much more than that, you'll need to adapt it or create a map from the unique values in columns to `start, mid, end`

Comment: nice point about amount of data... I had to mention it in my q...

Answer (score 2):

Using only pandas:

```py
(
    df['Timestamp'].groupby(df['Date']).agg(['min','median','max']).merge(df, on='Date')
    .melt(id_vars=['Values','Date'], var_name='Period', value_name='Datetime')
    .query('Period!="Timestamp"')
    .sort_values('Datetime')
)
```

Output:

```
   Values       Date  Period            Datetime
0    absd 2022-05-25     min 2022-05-25 08:00:00
1    abse 2022-05-25     min 2022-05-25 08:00:00
2    dara 2022-05-25     min 2022-05-25 08:00:00
7    abse 2022-05-25  median 2022-05-25 11:30:00
6    absd 2022-05-25  median 2022-05-25 11:30:00
8    dara 2022-05-25  median 2022-05-25 11:30:00
12   absd 2022-05-25     max 2022-05-25 20:25:00
13   abse 2022-05-25     max 2022-05-25 20:25:00
14   dara 2022-05-25     max 2022-05-25 20:25:00
4    abse 2022-05-26     min 2022-05-26 09:00:00
3    absd 2022-05-26     min 2022-05-26 09:00:00
5    dara 2022-05-26     min 2022-05-26 09:00:00
9    absd 2022-05-26  median 2022-05-26 13:40:00
10   abse 2022-05-26  median 2022-05-26 13:40:00
11   dara 2022-05-26  median 2022-05-26 13:40:00
16   abse 2022-05-26     max 2022-05-26 19:15:00
15   absd 2022-05-26     max 2022-05-26 19:15:00
17   dara 2022-05-26     max 2022-05-26 19:15:00
```

Comment: ach.... I missed `.query('Period!="Timestamp"')` :) I was quite close with the rest in my tests! :) Thanks a lot! :)